# How can I generate code based on content of the other module?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have to generate kotlin code based on types from an external module.

```
Example project:
|-Base
| |-interface ContentProvider
|
|-First
| |-interface FirstProvider : ContentProvider
|
|-Second
| |-interface SecondProvider : ContentProvider
|
|-Main app
  |-class providers (generated)
    |- object : FirstProvider
    |- object : SecondProvider
```

So, I have to generate class providers which contains implementation of each descendant of ContentProvider

I have tried to use KSP to achieve that, but KSP has not an access to content of an other module.

I need some idea how it could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

##### Write a new classpath scanning program

- In a new Gradle module, write a Kotlin JVM program with a JVM classpath scanner as dependency (eg [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) (a bit easier to use, but not in active development) or [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) (more modern and supposedly faster)).
- Have that program accept arguments specifying (i) a destination directory for new code (this would normally be somewhere in target project's `build` directory) and (ii) the path of module(s) to be scanned.
- Have that program scan the classpath of those modules and generate whatever code files you desire into the code directory. Some use [Kotlin Poet](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/) to write the code, but I prefer just to generate it by hand<sup>1</sup>.

##### Write a new Gradle task

- Write a new Gradle task, which has running that JVM program with those arguments as its task action. You can use [`Project.javaexec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:javaexec(groovy.lang.Closure))<sup>2</sup> in the task action, or extend the [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) class.
- The new task should declare as inputs the classpath scanning program JAR and the module(s) to be scanned in `FileCollection` objects; and declare as an output directory the generated source directory.
- To get your hands on the JAR with your new classpath scanner in, set up a new [configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) in the target project and put the classpath scanning project as its dependency. You can then resolve that configuration to get the JAR and pass it to your new task.
- You can similarly use a configuration to capture the module(s) you are scanning.
- Declare your output directory as part of the Kotlin source so it's included in the compilation.

##### Write a Gradle plugin

- All of that build code is probably best written outside of a build script, so package it in a plugin if you can and apply it in your target project(s).
- Have that plugin [declare an extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build) which facilitates you capturing the module(s) to be scanned in target project build scripts, if appropriate.

---

<sup>1</sup> If generating by hand, I recommend using the `org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language` annotation on functions returning a code string as this provides some basic formatting in your target language

<sup>2</sup> If using the configuration cache, this needs to called from `ExecOperations` ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/8.7-rc-2/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:use_project_during_execution))

Comment: Thank you, I'll investigate this way. It seems as an option to solve my task.